# Set video poster different size than video element

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I have an html5 `video` element that is sized with css to cover the entire screen.

```
video#myVideo {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I have the `poster` attribute set to an image that I want to be a smaller size (e.g. 100px by 100px).

Is there a way to access and set the poster css, e.g. `video#myVideo[poster]`? Or any ideas how I can change my css to both cover the screen for the video and only render a smaller poster image?

**Updated explanation:**

The goal is to have the video cover the entire screen when there is a source and the poster image (or another separate image) only cover a smaller section (i.e. not stretched to 100%).

My current attempt is to not use the poster attribute and instead do:

```
<div>
  <img ... />
  <video ... />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it doesn't look like it's possible. On the other hand, this looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's best if you describe your goal.

Comment: @Amit I added an updated explanation. You're correct, I don't need to use the poster attribute so a different solution could be possible.